# Firebase Cloud function request.body empty or undefined

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const Razorpay = require("razorpay");
const cors = require("cors")({origin: true});

exports.razorpayverification = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
        try {
          const name = JSON.stringify(req.body);
          console.log(req.body, name);
          res.status(200).json({status: "ok"});
          // I need req.body.amount value. req.body is empty. but JSON.stringify(req.body) contains all the data.
        } catch (error) {
          res.status(400).json({error: "JSON error"});
          res.end();
        }
    });
```

I am using the above cloud function and receiving payment data from Razorpay webhooks. In my console.log I have called req.body and name (const name = JSON.stringify(req.body);). name returns the data in string format and contains all information like orderid, payment id, amount etc but req.body is empty or undefined. I tried enclosing the above within cors but still the same result. Kindly let me know how to read req.body. I need to read req.body.amount.

Output:

```
req.body:
{

name: {"entity":"event","account_id":"acc_IvsP3zm1EoP7me","event":"payment.captured","contains":["payment"],"payload":{"payment":{"entity":{"id":"pay_J9fXFPd7T9uWo5","entity":"payment","amount":1000,"currency":"INR","status":"captured","order_id":"order_J9fWySTzmrenBl","invoice_id":null,"international":false,"method":"card","amount_refunded":0,"refund_status":null,"captured":true,"description":"Recharge","card_id":"card_J9fXFSITSAyVdB","card":{"id":"card_J9fXFSITSAyVdB","entity":"card","name":"k","last4":"1111","network":"Visa","type":"debit","issuer":null,"international":false,"emi":false,"sub_type":"consumer","token_iin":null},"bank":null,"wallet":null,"vpa":null,"email":"test@test.com","contact":"+16505551234","notes":{"key1":"otzo","key2":"recharge","address":"Razorpay Corporate Office"},"fee":20,"tax":0,"error_code":null,"error_description":null,"error_source":null,"error_step":null,"error_reason":null,"acquirer_data":{"auth_code":"213319"},"created_at":1647850380}}},"created_at":1647850385}
```

As shown req.body returns only the open curly braces and nothing after that. name returns all the data.

Comment: Can you `console.log(req.body)` and share the output?  Also can you add code where you are calling this function?

Comment: What **exactly** is the output from `console.log(req.body, name);`? Please [edit] it into your question.

Comment: Thanks Phil & Dharmaraj for replying. I have added the output for your perusal

Comment: Can you go through [this](https://erikmartinjordan.com/undefined-post-request-firebase) similar issue. which might be helpful for you.

Comment: Thanks Roopa for pointing the link. I tried with CORS but unable to get req.body data Same output as mentioned above.

Comment: According to this [document](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/http#terminating_http_functions).  _Any tasks not terminated prior to an HTTP response may cause undefined behavior_. Have you gone through this document before?

Comment: I have terminated all my HTTP responses. Anyway now I found the solution.

Comment: Thanks Roopa once again for your valuable input

Answer (score 1):

Not sure this is the correct answer but my code was executing properly and I was receiving the `res.body`. But the issue lies in the console.log which did not display. if it is a multi-level object firebase cloud function is not displaying properly. Below is the Razorpays Payments Sample Payload. `res.body` displays only the open-end curly bracket. `res.body.payload` created a log with all the details under the payload section. Again here firebase cloud function displays each and every field as a separate log.

```json
{
   "entity":"event",
   "account_id":"acc_BFQ7uQEaa7j2z7",
   "event":"payment.authorized",
   "contains":[
      "payment"
   ],
   "payload":{
      "payment":{
         "entity":{
            "id":"pay_DESlfW9H8K9uqM",
            "entity":"payment",
            "amount":100,
            "currency":"INR",
            "status":"authorized",
            "order_id":"order_DESlLckIVRkHWj",
            "invoice_id":null,
            "international":false,
            "method":"netbanking",
            "amount_refunded":0,
            "refund_status":null,
            "captured":false,
            "description":null,
            "card_id":null,
            "bank":"HDFC",
            "wallet":null,
            "vpa":null,
            "email":"gaurav.kumar@example.com",
            "contact":"+919876543210",
            "notes":[
               
            ],
            "fee":null,
            "tax":null,
            "error_code":null,
            "error_description":null,
            "error_source":null,
            "error_step":null,
            "error_reason":null,
            "acquirer_data":{
               "bank_transaction_id":"0125836177"
            },
            "created_at":1567674599
         }
      }
   },
   "created_at":1567674606
}
```